# How to trigger jenkins pipeline only on merge to develop branch from github webhook trigger?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am having a problem to trigger Jenkins pipeline job based on merge any branches to develop branch only. I also did not find any webhook for merge as like bitbucket. I also tried using pull request but that triggered the job on any changes to the PR branch which is not my requirement.

I have also shared my code below and my Jenkins Configuration.
[Jenkins Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhcDV.png) also please note that it is develop branch but in the image I've shown `*/feature` I have changed it to develop but still the issue is the same.

```
def CONTAINER_NAME=""
def CONTAINER_TAG="${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
def CONTAINER_PORT=""
def ECR_REPO=""
def HOST_PORT=""
def URL=""
def INSTANCE_IP=""

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Image Build Develop') {
      when {
        expression {
         return env.BRANCH_NAME != 'feature_cicd'
         echo env.BRANCH_NAME
        }
      } 
      steps {
        git branch: "develop", url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-parameter-plugin.git' 
        imageBuildDevelop(CONTAINER_NAME, CONTAINER_TAG)
        }
    }

    stage('Image Tag') {
      steps {
        imageTag(CONTAINER_NAME, CONTAINER_TAG, ECR_REPO)
      }
    }

    stage('Image Push') {
      steps {
        imagePush(CONTAINER_NAME, CONTAINER_TAG, ECR_REPO)
      }
    }

    stage('Image Deploy') {
      steps {
        imageDeploy(HOST_PORT, env.BUILD_NUMBER, INSTANCE_IP)
      }
    }
  }
}

def imageBuildDevelop(containerName, tag) {
  echo "#------------------- Checkout Develop Branch -------------------#"
  git branch: "feature_cicd", url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-parameter-plugin.git'
  echo "#------------------- Login into ECR Repository -------------------#"
  sh "`/var/jenkins_home/.local/bin/aws ecr get-login --no-include-email`"
  echo "#------------------- Build Docker Image for Media-API -------------------#"
  sh "docker build -t $containerName:$tag -t $containerName ."
  echo "#------------------- Image Build Complete -------------------#"
}

def imageTag(containerName, tag, repo) {
  echo "#------------------- Tag media-api image -------------------#"
  sh "docker tag $containerName:$tag $repo:$containerName-$tag"
  echo "#------------------- Image Tag Complete ------------------#"
}

def imagePush(containerName, tag, repo) {
  echo "#------------------- Login into ECR Repository -------------------#"
  sh "`/var/jenkins_home/.local/bin/aws ecr get-login --no-include-email`"
  echo "#------------------- Push Image into ECR Repository -------------------#"
  sh "docker push $repo:$containerName-$tag"
  echo "#------------------- Image Push to ECR Repository Complete -------------------#"
}

def imageDeploy(hostPort, tag, ip) {
  echo "#------------------- SSH into media-api instance -------------------#"
  sh "ssh ubuntu@$ip \"BUILD_NUMBER=$tag\" \
  ' cd reactApi_test/ &&\
    echo \"TAG=${BUILD_NUMBER}\" > .env &&\
    `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email` &&\
    docker-compose up -d --build &&\
    ./test.sh '"
  echo "#------------------- Media-API container started on Port '${hostPort} (http)' -------------------#"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the CHANGE_TARGET environment variable.  If that variable exists then you are dealing with a merge request.

You can use the following code snipped to then determine the branch name and alter the job's logic depending on which branch the code is being merged into.

`branchName = env.CHANGE_TARGET ? env.CHANGE_TARGET : env.BRANCH_NAME`

In your code example you would replace

```
        expression {
         return env.BRANCH_NAME != 'feature_cicd'
         echo env.BRANCH_NAME
        }
```

with

```
        expression {
         branchName = env.CHANGE_TARGET ? env.CHANGE_TARGET : env.BRANCH_NAME
         return branchName != 'feature_cicd'
         echo branchName
        }
```

Comment: where should I define this.
Can you help me with that?
Since I want it to be triggered based on different branches.
Say, if any push or merge is done in the master branch, I want to trigger only master branch jobs and for changes in develop branch, I want to trigger only develop branch jobs.

Comment: There are two seperate issues.
1. What is the relevant branch for this PR
2. Does the job run at all?
For issue 2 you need to change the jenkins pipeline setttings in the job configuration. There's a few plugins for that.

Comment: 1. The relevant branch for PR is develop branch for now. But I have to do the same for master as well.
2. This job does runs for develop branch as you have also seen the image.

Comment: @Manish_ I've edited my answer.

Comment: I checked it, but it is returning null for env.BRANCH_NAME

Comment: branchName will default to CHANGE_TARGET if the current code isn't working try ${env.CHANGE_TARGET} and ${env.BRANCH_NAME} instead.

Comment: Thank you it solved the issue.
What is the case for multiple branches? Where should I make changes?

Comment: Have conditions based in the value of branchame.

Comment: When i use this and instead of return branchName != 'feature_cicd', when I use  return branchName == 'master', my steps does not execute with the console output of Jenkins referring to, skipping stage due to when condition.
Am I doing something worng or is it the way Jenkins behave?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding sorry.  Maybe edit your question with the current code and problem?

Comment: I have solved the issue.
Thank you for your help.